# Should questions be edited to remove distasteful expressions?

Tags: discussion, editing

Should I edit this question [Yom Kippur, fasting, and snot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31837/yom-kippur-fasting-and-snot) or this one [Pulling out hairs while wiping yourself on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31836/pulling-out-hairs-while-wiping-your-bum-on-shabbat) to replace the short slang words with less distasteful expressions?

Or am I being excessively sensitive?

Comment: I changed one word in the title of the second because (a) front page and (b) tweeted.  From the edit history it looked like that'd be ok with the OP.

Comment: Tangentially related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-modest-should-this-site-be http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/should-we-censor-the-term-goy-when-used-in-english-to-mean-gentile

Comment: I posted both questions. I edit Wikipedia and am a big believer in editing freely. Dear all: please do edit both questions however you like.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you're being overly sensitive in general. And Judaism puts a value on tasteful language. (Citation needed. I think it's on *daf* 2 of *P'sachim*.)

That said, I think *snot* is tasteful enough (and what else would you call it?).

*Bum* is not really in use in the States, and I'm not entirely sure of its [register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29) elsewhere, but if (as I suspect) it's analogous to American *butt* then I think it should be edited to something more tasteful like (American) *bottom* or *rear end*  or *derriere*.

Besides the individual words used, there's also (and IMO as important) the prose used: how the words are put together. [I edited one of the questions you mention](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/31836/revisions) to remove an anatomical description that (besides its needing to be reworded as vulgar) was completely unnecessary (implied by context) so removable.

Comment: Thanks for the edit of the second question. I agree the need to use refined language in Judaism. Btw, Wikipedia says "Snot is slang for nasal mucus or dried nasal mucus".

Comment: I wouldn't see *bum* as being in a low register at all. Of course, euphemisms around that part of the anatomy are many and varied. You get a euphemism treadmill effect, and it can be hard to keep up with it.

Comment: I edited "bum" out of the title because, while not vulgar like some other words for that part of the body, I find it a little distasteful and unprofessional and I think we can do better when publishing to the whole world (and the experts we seek in particular).

Comment: @MonicaCellio, excellent point, worthy of being posted as an answer here IMO.

Comment: If the word is distasteful, @MonicaCellio, there must be some other word for a *bum bag*, and, to be honest, I can't think of any (except *fanny pack*, which has its own many many problems). I think that even in the most formal register, I would call a bum bag a bum bag; I thereby infer that *bum* is not a distasteful word.

Comment: @TRiG I'd never heard of a "bum bag" before now.  (I know it as a "fanny pack".)  The distaste comes from context; if I heard it in a casual setting (or Yahoo Answers :-) ) I'd probably shrug, but I'm looking for more maturity here.

Comment: @msh210 I already upvoted your answer and see my comment as a minor augment; do you see it as different enough that I should make it its own answer?

Comment: Well, just as a tip, @MonicaCellio, you do *not* want to use the phrase *fanny pack* on this side of the Atlantic. (a) No one will know what you mean, and (b) over here, *fanny* means "vagina", not "bottom".

Comment: *blink* Thank you for that tip.